# PHP - OOP Seperation of logic and html with error

Tags: php, oop, variables, scope

I'm getting the following PHP error from a form that calls a method from a class that validates a form and returns errors if any.
Here is the error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function frm_errors() on a non-object

I just wrapping my head around OOP and I think it has to do with the scope of the object $validation which is an instance of the class Validate.

Here is the code that produces the error.

```
<?php echo "<p class='error'>" . $validation->frm_errors('username') . "</p>"; ?>
```

I can fix the error by modifying the code as follows:

```
<?php if(isset($validation)) {echo "<p class='error'>" . $validation->frm_errors('username') . "</p>"; } ?>
```

It doesn't seem like good practice to include that mod in every output of the form.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: I think it does make sense to do that. If the `$validation` variable is null, then it means that there's no error and thus you shouldn't have to echo out a `<p class='error'>`.

Comment: the error means that $validation is never instantiated.

Comment: I guess I was on the right track then. Something just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Is there anyway to instantiate $validation to an empty string when the form first opens, before the submit button has been clicked?